# UPDATE Only one row (using update and join)

Tags: mysql, join, update, limits

I'm trying to get a fast, simple sql query to update only one row at a time while using join too.

I have tried `LIMIT`, but to no success.

Query:

```
UPDATE
table1
JOIN
table2 ON table2.col=table1.col
SET 
table1.row1='a value'
WHERE
table1.row2 LIKE '%something%' 
LIMIT 1
```

Message:

> Error Code: 1221. Incorrect usage of UPDATE and LIMIT

Comment: Your accounts have now been merged. You can edit your question, leave comments, and accept an answer.

Answer (score 7):

`LIMIT` is not allowed when the `UPDATE` has joins. You can however move the join and the `LIMIT` inside a subquery and then join back to the table to be updated using the primary or a unique key. This is allowed:

```
UPDATE table1 AS upd
  JOIN
    ( SELECT t1.pk
      FROM table1 AS t1
        JOIN
           table2 AS t2 ON t2.col = t1.col
      WHERE t1.row2 LIKE '%something%' 
      -- ORDER BY some_expressions
      LIMIT 1
    ) AS sel
    ON sel.pk = upd.pk
SET 
   upd.row1 = 'a value' ;
```

It's also good to use `ORDER BY` with `LIMIT`. Otherwise an arbitrary row will be selected.

---

If you want to update both tables (one row from each one), then you just need to join the derived table to the second table, too:

```
UPDATE 
    ( SELECT t1.pk AS pk1,                     -- The PK columns 
             t2.pk AS pk2                      -- of each table
      FROM table1 AS t1
        JOIN
           table2 AS t2 ON t2.col = t1.col
      WHERE t1.row2 LIKE '%something%' 
      -- ORDER BY some_expressions
      LIMIT 1
    ) AS sel
  JOIN table1 AS upd1  ON sel.pk1 = upd1.pk    -- join table1    
  JOIN table2 AS upd2  ON sel.pk2 = upd2.pk    -- join table2
SET 
   upd1.row1 = 'a value',
   upd2.roww = 'some other value' ;
```

Test at [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/ASNV5935)

Comment: it does not work with temporary table http://rextester.com/GVDFW43496

Comment: No, you can't join a temp table twice in MySQL.

Comment: Nice, but can't you use `IN(...)` instead of `JOIN(...)`?